# Allow Posts and Discussions to use same Categories lookup field

Tags: lookup-column, blog, discussion-board, ssom

I am creating a Community site and activating the `BlogContent` feature on that site. There are conflicting issues, because the Community Site and the `BlogContent` feature both create a `Lookup List` called `Categories`. (Please see inline comments for reasoning)

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("MySite"))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        //Creating a community site automatically creates a list "Categories" which is to be used
        //as a lookup field for the Discussions List.
        SPWeb newWeb = web.Webs.Add("Name", "DisplayName", "Description", 1033, "COMMUNITY#0", false, false); 
        newWeb.Navigation.UseShared = true;
        //Guid to "BlogContent" feature. Activate this feature because I need blogs to be on the same 
        //site as a discussion board. This feature too, creates a "Categories" list which is used
        //as a lookup field for blog posts.
        newWeb.Features.Add(new Guid("0d1c50f7-0309-431c-adfb-b777d5473a65"));
        newWeb.Update();
        success = true;
   } 
}
```

The above runs fine and I get my `Discussions List` and `Posts` list as wanted:

[image]

The issue, however, is that the `Categories`list throws errors when accessing List Settings or when adding new items. I also see this error when browsing to the blog list:

[image]

It is the `Webpart` that dynamically builds a navigation based off of the `Categories` list.

How can I allow both the `Discussions List` and the `Posts` list to use the `Categories` list as a reference for a lookup field? And how do I resolve the error being thrown by the `Categories` list when trying to access its settings?

Answer (score 0):

This really isn't supported, so test at your own risk.

1. Remove or delete Categories list (used by discussions).
2. Activate BlogContent
3. Add Posts and BlogTools webparts
4. Add link from discussions list to new Categories list.

(for #1 and #4 I'm thinking whether to create a new temporary list and change the lookup definition in discussion list to the temp list, before deleting the old categories).